# pinterest url debugger causes redirect loop

Tags: debugging, pinterest, microdata

According to the pinterest documentation microdata in webistes has to be checked via pinterest's `url-debugger` at least once before pinterest starts to read it.

Unfortunately I'm having some trouble with pinterest's debugger [here](http://developers.pinterest.com/tools/url-debugger/)

Even when I'm logged in the debugger page asks me to log in. After I did so the site keep reloading over and over again with a frequency of a few seconds. So I'm not even getting to load the debugger page.

Is this a bug on pinterest's side or am I doing anything wrong? Can anyone reproduce the bug?